# What are the most significant breast tissues in Gynecomastia?

Tags: surgery, scar-tissue-scars, gynecomastia-man-boobs

From prior research I understand that only these types of tissues can cause [gynecomastia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynecomastia):

- [Adipose tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipose_tissue) ("watery")
- [Mammary Gland Tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammary_gland) ("viscous")
- Excessive skin tissue ("saggy")
- [Connective Tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connective_tissue) fibrosis ("harsh")

I further understand that the similar problem lipomastia is specified by excessive *Adipose tissue* in chest with very little (sub clinical) amount, if at all, of Mammary Gland Tissue `and/or` Connective Tissue `and/or` Excessive skin tissue hence treatment is primarily liposuction or other anti-adipose therapies.

### My problem

I might understand wrong in regards to both gynecomastia and lipomastia and excessive [chest lobe tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobe_(anatomy)) is also significant, if not at least a possible cause.

### My question

What are the most significant breast tissues in Gynecomastia?

Comment: Are you asking about proportions of each type of tissues or commonalities between each type found in gynaecomastia?

Comment: Hello ; indeed by proportion; I mean which ones are more common than which.

Comment: I think you're confusing gynecomastia and pseudogynecomastia.